# Undefined symbol: _OBJC_CLASS_$_FIRApp

Tags: objective-c, firebase, firebase-analytics, xcode12, swift-package-manager

I m trying to add Firebase Analytic and Firebase Crashlytics using Swift package manager here is a link of git for firebase SDK
https://github.com/firebase/firebase-ios-sdk

after that I add this two line in my AppDelegate file

> #import <FirebaseCore/FIRApp.h>

> #import <Firebase.h>

All fine until when I add this `[FIRApp configure];` getting error

> Undefined symbols for architecture arm64:
> "*OBJC_CLASS*$_FIRApp", referenced from:
> objc-class-ref in HWOFAppDelegate.o
> ld: symbol(s) not found for architecture arm64
> clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)

I go thought every link of stack-overflow for similar problem try every solution but nothing help me like change Other Linker Flag etc...
Please help me..I really appreciate...I m using Xcode 12.1 with Objective-C
here is a screenshot of error which i m getting

[image]

And screenshot of added dependency

[image]

Comment: Swift dependency package is swift package manager?

Comment: yes using swift package manager

Comment: Does this manual not work https://github.com/firebase/firebase-ios-sdk/blob/master/SwiftPackageManager.md?

Comment: nope i tried... m not sure but maybe my project is so old because of that facing this issue..but i don't know how to solved

Comment: To old project should use cocoapods instead of SPM

Comment: Please provide Package.swift file

Comment: same i tried using cocoa but in cocoa pod i m not able to import firebase in my APPdelegate so after that m using swift package manager

Comment: Just `@import Firebase;`

Comment: https://safenote.co/r/5fabf1a57e4a77@32263035 here is link of Package of swift file

Comment: No luck using @import firebase

Answer (score 13, accepted):

After so much searched I solved issue. Solution is

1. "$(inherited)" In Other Linker Flags
2. Build Active Architecture Only value to "Yes"
3. Add Run Script for firebase SPM is "${BUILD_DIR%Build/*}SourcePackages/checkouts/firebase-ios-sdk/Crashlytics/run"
4. Clean project
5. Build Project

Comment: what will be script in case of pod not SPM

Comment: Doesn't "Build Active Architecture Only value to "Yes"" build only for the architecture of the machine you are building on? What happens when you build for a physical phone or to send to the app store?

Answer (score 2):

I got the same issue while integrating MLKit in my recent work. The app was running fine on simulator as well as device but when I tried to archive the build it started throwing me error below-:

```
Undefined symbol: _OBJC_CLASS_$_MLKFaceDetector
```

I am using the MLKFaceDetector object in my files.

**Resolution:-**

Go to Build Settings -> Architectures -> Replace standard architectures with **arm64**. Also, make sure there is no space between arm & 64.

Reason what I understood is MLKit only supports 64 bit not 32 bit and since we are using standard architectures targeting both 32 and 64 bit, so Xcode while archiving for 32 bit is unable to find MLKit files. So we are explicitly saying Xcode to Archive only for 64 bit and not 32 bit.

**Cons** - It will not support some of the older iOS devices.

Comment: For me, only this solution worked. On which older iOS devices would work? The accepted solution didn't work. Also, did you find anything, later on, that would make it work on older devices too?

Comment: It wont work on older devices since they support only 32 bit but it wont affect much as almost all the devices supported by Apple now are 64 bit.

Comment: Thanks! However, when I did these changes, I got a different error:
`FBLPromises.h file not found`

It is coming under `GoogleUtilities_Environment`

Answer (score 1):

Finally I found the solution for this
For me changing ios deployment target to higher version than before workd.Mine was 9.0 I changed it to 13 .

Target-general- deployment info

Answer (score -1):

Can try this it Will help,

Change Linking -> Mach-O Type to Dynamic Library, for the frameworks you used, then it works fine.

[image: Screenshot]

Answer (score -1):

I had to update my OS and xcode to the latest version for it to work.